# Is DNS redirection scenario possible?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dns-hosting, plesk

I have a question regarding DNS, assuming I have my domain register pointed to an external DNS, is it possible for me redirect it to another DNS if something isn't found.

I am asking because of ACME changing every 3 months, which I would not like to manually update.

Comment: "redirection" is not really a term applicable at the DNS level. "redirection" comes from the HTTP layer. A `CNAME` is an alias, so semantically slightly different. And `NS` records are for delegations, which are a far stronger mechanism than an HTTP redirection where you map one URL to another URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't make that redirect conditional, but as also the Let's Encrypt documentation explains [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge), you can **use DNS `CNAME` records** or **`NS` records** to delegate specific records (and answering the DNS-01 challenge)  to other DNS zones and/or servers.
That is a perfectly sound solution in case your current DNS provider doesn't provide a DNS API for automation and you cannot switch completely to a different provider.

```
 _acme-challenge.example.com.  IN CNAME example-com.example.co.uk.
```

where you use a single record `example-com.example.co.uk. in TXT "challenge"` in an existing DNS zone or

```
_acme-challenge.example.com.  IN NS example-com.example.co.uk.
```

where you set up a completely new zone that is authoritative  for `*._acme-challenge.example.com.` including `_acme-challenge.example.com.` itself.